# A function which takes name of global variable as input and changes its value

Tags: c++

I have a global variable x, and I want to write a function which checks if x is greater than or equal to 700, and if it is, I want to set x to 100.

Now if I write a simple if statement, as shown below, it works fine.

However, if I take x and instead I put it as the input of a function consisting of that if statement it stops working. How do I fix that?

Please don't tell me to do it using an alternative method, because it's not so much about getting the job done, as it is about learning how to do it the way I want it to be done.

I tried putting "::" in front of the x in the if statement in the second block of code, but that didn't work. I've scoured the internet but found nothing useful.

This is a simple if statement and it **works fine**, after the code is ran, the value of x is set to 100:

```cpp
x = 800;
if (x >= 700) {
    x = 100;
}
```

Now I put it into a function and it **stops working**; after the code is ran, x is still equal to 800:

```cpp
x = 800
void function(int x) {
    if (x >= 700) {
        x = 100;
    }
```

I don't get any error messages or anything, the function just does nothing, it lets x stay at 800, and the program acts as if the function isn't there.

Comment: There could be many possible reasons for that. Because of that, until you [edit] your question so that it meets all requirements of a [mre] as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help], it is unlikely that anyone will have any idea what's the problem with your code. Additionally, see some tips for [ask] questions here so that they're actually answerable.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because the variable `x` inside the function isn't the same as the global variable `x`. Let's rename it to make it clear:

```
void function(int function_x) {
    if (function_x >= 700) {
        function_x = 100;
    }
}

// later:
x = 701;
function(x);
```

Now `x` is 701 and `function_x` is 701. Then the function makes `function_x` 100. But `x` is still 701.

So, how can you change this so the function does change `x`? The most straightforward change is to make `function_x` a reference, by adding `&`:

```
//                |
//                |
//                V
void function(int &function_x) {
    if (function_x >= 700) {
        function_x = 100;
    }
}

// later:
x = 701;
function(x);
```

Now, instead of just passing the number `701` to `function`, it passes the location of `x`. Accessing `function_x` inside `function` now accesses the global variable `x` instead of the local variable in the function. Of course, you can pass *any* `int` variable and the function will update it:

```
int blah = 701;
function(blah);
// now blah's value is 100
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this is also a naming issue of sorts. If the input becomes `int function_x`, then modifying `x` will suddenly work as the OP seems to expect (sort of). However, to modify the passed value (and not just the global `x`), you will still need to pass by reference, which seems to be the real intended use of this function.